# Checking variables in XCODE after app has crashed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

My app has crashed telling that he index is out range when I use this `team[1]` which is surprising because it should have 2 strings in it. I have looked everywhere, in XCODE and the internet, but cannot find a way to see what the team array looks like. Is there anyway to see this? Thanks so much!

Comment: maybe you can show some of your codes?

Comment: use dump(team) and check the number of values it contains.

Comment: @koropok i was just wondering if there is a feature in the XCODE debugger that let's you check the value of the variable. In the playground it works fine, but not in the view controller.

Comment: you can put a breakpoint and do a po teams on the log.

Comment: what is po teams?

Comment: @StefWG : check [link](http://prntscr.com/g9vki3)

Comment: thx just what i was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

click on the left side of your line of code which contains (`team[1]`) to create a breakpoint.

Then run your app. When it reaches that point it will stop executing so you can check what is going on.

**Here is an screenshot on how debugging looks like**

You can see your array content in the **"variables view"**
There is also an example of "po" command on the **"console"** section
[image]

If you just want **to use a breakpoint everytime your app crashes** just add an **exception breakpoint**. This should show you where your code crashes and stop just before so you can find out what happened

[image]